# Install SharePoint package on an NLB Cluster

Tags: installation, infrastructure

I am trying to test a SharePoint package installation on a VPC environment.

I have set up an NLB cluster with two VPC's. One problem may be that I have only one network card configured on the VPC's.(using multicast)

When we run the install on one of the NLB web we are unable to give the nlb address, when we give the address of one of the servers, the package only gets installed on that server.

Should we run the package from a machine outside the cluster, or is there another way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have your Alternate Access Mappings setup correctly to be able to use the NLB address?  Also, I'm pretty sure you need to have another nic for server to server communication.  If you are using Microsoft Windows NLB, typically you won't be able to communicate with the other servers in the NLB through the interface that is load balanced, thus you need an additional interface that they can communicate through.

Comment: Thanks we fixed this by adding an extra network card to each web server, then running the package on one of the web servers